# Rethinkdb, Go: Ensure Table and Index in one ReQL statement

Tags: go, rethinkdb

I need to ensure existence of table(s) upon application startup.

I also want to create secondary index on the table if table does not exist and needs to be created.

It is easily done in Go but I would like to do it in ReQL in one statement. So I came up with this:

```
func ensureTableIndex(ses *r.Session, name string, index string) (err error) {
    err = r.TableList().Contains(name).Do(r.Branch(r.Row, r.Expr(nil), r.Do(func() r.Term {
        return r.TableCreate(name).Do(func() r.Term {
            return r.Table(name).IndexCreate(index)
        })
    }))).Exec(ses)
    return
}
```

Seems to pass the test.

My question is whether this is a correct/efficient way to do table and index creation in one go? Is using ReQL Do() function the correct way to sequence multiple write commands?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, `do` is the normal way you sequence operations in ReQL.  The `r.Do` as the third argument to `branch` is superfluous, though; you can just put the `tableCreate` call there directly.